# Will CSS position:fixed block event handling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Show you code first:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-fog-te1bw?file=/index.html

Please focus on two points:

1. `full-size-bg` is full screen background, it use a fixed div to adjust the alpha instead of set background to parent node because I do not want to modify the real image alpha.
2. `scroll-area` is above the `full-size-bg` and it`s(should be) a scrollable area which height is longer than visible area

Then what I want to know is the fixed background will block the event handling if I do not add `position: absolute` in `scroll-area`, the scroll area can not scroll with mouse wheel(but it can scroll if use up and down arrow key, Why?). Of course `fiexed` will leave document flow for layouting, but also for event handling?

Second, Chrome do not need add the `z-index` line, but Firefox need, Why??

Third, What I need now is a standard way to set a full screen background with alpha programmatically?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, in your example code, the `fixed` position does not prevent scrolling. The problem is, when you don't set `position: absolute` for `scroll-area` div, the `full-size-bg` div is **HIGHER** z-index. You can see that by inspecting in developer tool by right clicking, it will show the top "front" element.

You can find an answer here also: [z-index not working with fixed positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning).

For question about firefox vs chrome z-index, you can see more here: [z-index behaviour is different in chrome to firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646746/z-index-behaviour-is-different-in-chrome-to-firefox/31710969)

For third question, I don't understand correctly :(