# Z-index displays differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, z-index

I have 2 components, navBar and wings animation, so the issue is that in chrome it works properly(navBar is under wings), but in fireFox navBar is on top of wingsAnimation
I know that browsers have different engines but don't have enough exp to fix that[image: screen of issue]

```
.navBarWrap {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.wingWrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100 !important;
  transform: translateY(10rem);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (including the HTML), ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646746/z-index-behaviour-is-different-in-chrome-to-firefox/31710969 (thank you [Kruno Golubic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17781575/kruno-golubic) for finding it).

Comment: The dupe gives me the same results in both Chrome and Fx in 2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a question from 6 years ago could help you. Take a look at "[z-index behaviour is different in chrome to firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646746/z-index-behaviour-is-different-in-chrome-to-firefox/31710969)". Does this help you?

Comment: Do users with your rep not have access to the "close" link on the question? (This is not snark, this is a genuine question.) I thought everyone did. If you think the answer you've linked answers the question, that's what you should do: click close and say it's a duplicate, pasting in that link. The answer box is for *new* answers.

Comment: I don't see that option. I have "Share Edit Follow Flag". I don't see Link option so I guess I'm to "low" for that. I'm rather new here, I have a reputation of only 58. And I can see that for proposing to close the question I [need 3000 at least](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought you could propose a duplicate without actually having a close vote option (basically to bring it to the attention of the OP and to other people who could actually vote to close). Well, now that you have a rep >= 50 (you didn't when you posted this, but you do now), you can use a comment to suggest it in future.