# Using `*` selector for transition results in asynchronous effect

Tags: css

In writing some html, I was too lazy to decide a more specific CSS selector like this:

```
    #z {
        transition-duration:0s;
        transition-delay:1s;
    }
```

So I had chosen the `*` selector instead.

I was surprised with the result of this code. Try it:

```css
* {
  transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

#z {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

#z:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="z">
    <span>mouse hover here!</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In my browser, transitions take effect in two steps: `background-color` changes after a 1s delay, followed by the change of `color` after **another** 1s delay.

If I switch back from the `*` selector to a more specific selector, transitions will be simultaneous. Is it browser specific? What is the relevant rule for this result?

EDIT:
1(question rephrased) Is there any specification made by CSS that every browser **should** follow to implement in this way(as described above), or this is up to browser or even hardware performance?
2\ I've tried it on Chrome, and a browser on an android mobile phone (a touch for a hover). Both produce the same result.

Comment: Don't ask if it's browser specific when YOU can test it in other browsers! Seems to work fine in FF and as you describe in chromium

Comment: @ZachJensz Thanks for your comment. Perhaps a rephrase of my question is desired. I can test on another browser, but I cannot determine whether the browser is buggy, or the definition of CSS actually does specify such behaviour every browser **should** follow. P

Comment: I have looked through the [Chrome User Agent Stylesheet](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css) and can't find anything buggy like you suggest. gtg but if no answer when I get back I will continue searching

Comment: I suspect the issue to be inheritance related as removing the span tags around the text solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

### Chrome and Firefox seem to differ in how transition delay impacts inheritance.

The following CSS fixed your issue for me in chromium:

```css
#z * {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

It sets the transition delay back to 0 for all descendants of #z.

```css
* {
  transition-duration: 0;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

#z {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

#z:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

#z * {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="z">
  <span>mouse hover here!</span>
</div>
```

### Explanation:

The `*` Universal Selector selects elements of any type, so it's applying a transition delay to both `div#z` **and** `span`.

**Chrome** seems to interpret this as you wanting a delay for #z to change to white, and then a delay for span to inherit

Hover #z -- 1s --> white text on #z -- 1s --> span inherits white

**Firefox** seems to interpret this as you wanting a delay for #z to change to white and be inherited

Hover #z -- 1s --> white text on #z --> span inherits white immediately

Here is a crazy example with many nested elements:

```css
* {
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: .5rem;
  transition-duration: 0;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

#a {
  background-color: white;
}

#a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

/* This rule seems to stop the propagation
#c {
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
*/
```

```html
<div id="a">
  a
  <div id="b">
    b
    <div id="c">
      c
      <div id="d">
        d
        <div id="e">
          e
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: True, always the old browser Firefox is best, chrome and its variant does things for us very easily which makes problems at times,I remember [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710969/14862885)